# How to resolve the issue (testcafe-live not working) on tetscafe over @0.21.0

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, automated-tests, testcafe

After upgrading testcafe version from 0.21 to 0.23 over, we encountered a problem that testcafe-live become not working.

command.

```
testcafe-live chrome tests/menu/test0001.ts --screenshots my-fixture/chrome --trace-warnings
```

console message

```
(node:9808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at new TestRunner (D:\business\comp\Git\autotest\node_modules\testcafe-live\lib\test-runner.js:36:46)
at Controller.init (D:\business\comp\Git\autotest\node_modules\testcafe-live\lib\controller.js:26:27)
at tcArguments.parse.then (D:\business\comp\Git\autotest\node_modules\testcafe-live\lib\index.js:16:28)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
(node:9808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9808) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**what we tried(but not working)**

・remove node_modules and clean cache

```
del node_modules
npm clean cache
```

・According to this issue, modified the programs
 https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-live/issues/25
 https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-live/pull/30
 (I'm not sure that this issue is related to my issue)

the version of programs

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.9.4",
    "testcafe": "^1.0.0",
    "testcafe-browser-provider-puppeteer": "^1.4.0",
    "testcafe-live": "^0.1.4"
  },
```

I tried testcafe @0.23.0, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, but not working

node @v8.11.3

npm @5.6.0

OS windows10 pro

Could you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The separate `testcafe-live` CLI utility is now abandoned. All its functionality was integrated into the `testcafe` utility: [Live mode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/live-mode.html). Use `testcafe --live ...` instead of `testcafe-live ...`.

Comment: thank you so much.it worked!! and sorry for overlooking the information.